# basic use of C archives (libraries) with clang linker

Tags: c, linker, clang, libraries, unix-ar

I have a main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a;
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;
    printf ("Hello %p, %p\n", & i, & a);
    return 0;
}
```

and a separate file, `foo.c`, which contains my definition for the variable `a`:

```
int a;
```

If I build like this:

```
clang -c main.c foo.c
clang main.o foo.o
./a.out
```

all is well. But, if I do the following:

```
ar rvs bar.a foo.o
```

I get a warning that I don't understand

```
r - foo.o
warning: /<elided>/ranlib: 
warning for library: bar.a the table of contents is empty 
(no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

so I check my library, ensuring that my symbol is in there

```
nm bar.a

bar.a(foo.o):
0000000000000004 C _a
```

and then I do

```
clang main.o bar.a
```

I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_a", referenced from:
      _main in main-5121f1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what did I miss?

Comment: I think the trouble is that the `int a;` in `foo.c` is a tentative definition.  It is marked `C` (common) in the output from `nm`.  If you explicitly initialized (to `0` for consistency; to some non-zero value to make sure for testing purposes), I believe you'd have no problem.  I'm not completely convinced because at the end of a TU, tentative definitions should be converted to definitions.

Comment: @Jonathan -- that's it.  If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the trouble is that the `int a;` in `foo.c` is a tentative definition.  It is marked `C` (common) in the output from `nm`.  If you explicitly initialized (to `0` for consistency; to some non-zero value to make sure for testing purposes), I believe you'd have no problem.

I'm not completely convinced because at the end of a TU, tentative definitions should be converted to definitions:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.9.2 External Object Definitions
>
> ¶2 A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
> without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
> tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
> identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
> the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
> identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
> equal to 0.

See also [How do I share a variable between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how/1433387#1433387)

Comment: The observed behavior with clang 503.0.40 is that it does not convert tentatives to definitions when they're in `.a` files. My actual example was a big, nested struct of structs and arrays, for which I was creating memory pools in a separate TU and trying to link them from a library. From an object `.o`, no problem, but a library, no. The intializers for big, nested structs are non-trivial and it took me a while to create the MVP above. But just initializing the big, nested structs did solve my problem.

Comment: This seems like something clang should issue a pretty serious warning about, no?