# Why is clang reporting an undefined symbol for an extern variable referenced in a static library

Tags: c, linker-errors

I witnessed this error which is reproducible in `AppleClang 12.0.0` but not with `gcc 7.5.0`. The issue is that I have an `extern` variable defined in a static library which a different static library wants to use. The linker states that the symbol for the variable is undefined. I tried to come up with an as minimal as possible repro:

`externs.h`

```
extern int A;
```

`a.c`

```
int A;
```

`b.h`

```
void bar();
```

`b.c`

```
#include "externs.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void bar()
{
    A = 100;
    printf("%d\n", A);
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    bar();
}
```

`makefile`

```
liba.a: a.c
    gcc -c a.c -o a.o
    ar crs liba.a a.o

libb.a: b.c
    gcc -c b.c -o b.o
    ar crs libb.a b.o

program: main.c liba.a libb.a
    gcc main.c -L. -lb -la -o program
```

On Linux, this program compiles, links and runs without issue. On macOS (where `gcc` is `AppleClang`) I get the following output :

```
gcc -c a.c -o a.o
ar crs liba.a a.o
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: archive library: liba.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
gcc -c b.c -o b.o
ar crs libb.a b.o
gcc main.c -L. -lb -la -o program
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_A", referenced from:
      _bar in libb.a(b.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

AFAICT, the warning is a red herring. If I add a dummy function to `a.c`, the warning doesn't show. Further, if I inspect `liba.a` with `nm` I get the following output:

```
liba.a(a.o):
0000000000000004 C _A
```

If I *do* add a  dummy function `foo` (which doesn't even refer to `A`) to `liba.a` *and* invoke it from `main.c`, the linking issue gets magically resolved. It's as if *if and only if* `main.o` is dependent on a symbol in `liba.a`, *then* all the symbols of `liba.a` become available to anything that may be dependent on them.

Comment: Not of use to you, right now, but for what it's worth, I tried to reproduce this with clang on Ubuntu and did not replicate the error. I clang --version reports that I used `clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)`, compiled for `Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` and with `Thread model: posix`

Comment: Look at the warning on `a.o`: it seems the compiler did not create an `int A`. Seems it created an empty object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050575/basic-use-of-c-archives-libraries-with-clang-linker

Comment: @pmg That wouldn't explain why it works with `gcc` nor why it works if an additional function is added to `liba.a`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Then why would that symbol show up with `nm`?

Comment: @HansPassant That is it. If `A` is initialized with `= 0;`, the linking issue goes away. In my actual code, `int A` was actually a `struct`. Adding a `= {};` resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: Adding `a = {};` means you're not using a Standard C compiler for your code ... maybe C++, maybe an extension??

Comment: @pmg Interestingly, `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` produces no warning about it (by AppleClang). Would `a = {0};` be the standard way to initialize a `struct` to zero? Mind you, I don't mind it to be initialized with trash since it gets overwritten at runtime given user input.

Comment: Yes, the C Standard does not allow empty initializer list, so use `= {0}` to zero-initialize. You may want to add `-std=c11 -pedantic` to be *more* standard

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes ... If no `-std=xxx` is given clang defaults to `-std=gnu17`